# Are there any meaningless photo data sets?

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking for a dataset. All I want is just a background photo. It can be a building, a river, or a house. But it must be a natural picture, not a drawn picture. Is there such a data set? It would be better if it contained various environments.

Comment: In theory, you search images.google.com for "backgrounds", but I'm not sure how well that would work

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/)

> Beautiful, free images gifted by the world’s most generous community of photographers. Better than any royalty free or stock photos.

One example, is a photo with a random URL, where 200 and 300 are the resolution:

```
https:/picsum.photos/200/300/?random
```

Another option is to choose certain Collections or tags

```
https://unsplash.com/collections
```

There is also an [API](https://unsplash.com/developers).

The photos have an open [license](https://unsplash.com/license).

---

Here is a 3rd party bulk download tool: https://github.com/MehediH/Bulksplash